# CakePHP 1.3: passing an argument for an action

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I have a dropdown form that with option values 1, 2, and 3. When this form is submitted (`$this->Form->create('MyModel', array('action' => 'view'))`), I'd like one of these options to be an argument variable that gets passed into the action `view` and go to `controller/view/option_value` so that I can load some appropriate data using `option_value`.

I can't seem to have this `option_value` passed as the action argument. It's a POST data, so I do have this `option_value` available to me in the controller, but I thought it would be good to have the value in the URL also because this `view.ctp` allows the user to update some things and I want the user to be redirected to the referrer easily.

Any ideas? I *think* this is a client-side issue.. but I'm not yet familiar with Javascripts.

Edit:
Still looking into how to do this.. but for now, I am just redirecting the form-submitted page, which does not include the `option_value` in the URL, to the same page with the `option_value` as the parameter. It works for what I need, but if anyone would like to add an answer, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->create('MyModel', array('id' => 'myForm', 'action' => 'view'));
echo $this->Form->input('MyField', array('id' => 'myField'));
echo $this->Html->scriptStart();
?>
    $('#myForm').on('submit', null, null, function(evt) {
        var form  = $('myForm'),
            field = $('#myField');

        form.action += "/" + field.value;
        form.submit();

        evt.stopPropagation();
    });
<?php
echo $this->Html->scriptEnd();
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));

?>
```

Try that, you might have to tweak some stuff to your needs. Cheers.
-Andrew